# BoneCP JDK 5 Maven Depedendency

Tags: maven, java-5, bonecp

How do you have to configure maven to pull down the JDK5 version of BoneCP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify a classifier in the dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.jolbox</groupId>
    <artifactId>bonecp</artifactId>
    <version>0.7.1.RELEASE</version>
    <classifier>jdk5</classifier>
</dependency>
```

Version 0.8.0-rc1 works on JDK 5